# Getting request headers of an ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, http-headers

I wish to get full request headers that were used in an ajax call I make (jQuery). Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You may use network tab in inspector in Google Chrome, or in Firebug. There you can see all headers of all requests.